# How do I seal a 4+ mm gap between skirting board and slate tiles?

Tags: kitchens, flooring

I have a slate kitchen floor and wooden skirting on the walls around (no beading).  At some points around the wall there are gaps of around 4 mm or more.

I was thinking of simply stuffing paper in the gap and then using [polyfilla](http://www.poly.com.au/) to cover the gap (sanding it off and then re-painting the skirting).

Does this sound like a good idea?  I am worried about making a mess of the slate floor using polyfilla.

Comment: Is your floor uneven or your skirt/trim too high? Are you trying to fix it or cover it up?

Comment: The floor is uneven.  Basically I just want to seal the gap to prevent insects coming in and keeping the warmth in.

Comment: If bugs and cold air are coming in through this gap, you have bigger problems.  Trim is simply used to cover a junction between two different planes, where a gap or ugliness may exist.  Trim should have nothing to do with the seal of a building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [foam backer rod](http://www.bestmaterials.com/Backer_Rod.aspx) in the gaps, put down masking tape on the slate (and perhaps above the joint, on the skirting and fill with the polyfila or perhaps a colour matched latex based caulk.

Pull the masking tape right after smoothing the joint down with a finger.